# Adjust UIActivityIndicatorView position in AlertView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I've been trying to adjust the position of IndicatorView inside UIAlertView, but it never works. i tried to set for loadingIndicator `loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50)` but it didn't apply at all, take a look on this photo :

[image]

```
alert = UIAlertView(title: "Loading...", message: nil , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil)
        loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37))
        loadingIndicator.center = self.view.center
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        alert.setValue(loadingIndicator, forKey: "accessoryView")
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        alert.show();
```

Comment: You might also be interested in this class: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Try following code:

```
        var alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Loading...", message: nil , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil)
        var viewBack:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(83,0,100,100))

        var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37))
        loadingIndicator.center = viewBack.center
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        viewBack.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        viewBack.center = self.view.center
        alert.setValue(viewBack, forKey: "accessoryView")
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        alert.show();
```

Comment: but it become so huge, just adjusting the indicator little bit to the top without creating huge view to be always at the center of the alert  ?

Comment: Just change the size of `viewBack` then  you will get smaller view :) @AaoIi

Comment: `var viewBack:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(83,0,100,60))`

Comment: Ok then Go for it @AaoIi

Comment: how put on bottom?

Answer (score 1):

I tried many times add custom view to UIAlertView ,many strange things happen. You can choose to use this library it is not as beautiful as the UIAlertView, it may solve you problem.

[Custom iOS AlertView](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many `\n` as necessary in the message to create the space.

In your `ViewController.swift`:

```
lazy var alertController: UIAlertController = {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Loading", message: "\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = .black
    let loading = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 35, width: 50, height: 50))
    loading.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loading.style = .gray
    loading.startAnimating();
    alert.view.addSubview(loading)
    return alert
}()
```

And usage:

```
// to show loading wheel
present(alertController, animated: true)

// to hide loading wheel
dismiss(animated: true)
```

Visual output:

[image: Image showing a popup with the message Loading]

(Inspired by @AshishKakkad answer)